# ZSH: prompt expansion return code greater than

Tags: zsh, conditional-operator

The problem is (theoretically) simple. All I want is for my zsh prompt to print the return code if it is less than or equal to 128 and the corresponding signal when greater than 128. I cannot find any example of this being done and the [zsh docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Conditional-Substrings-in-Prompts) only specify how to do it

> if the exit status of the last command was *n*

The only version I have got (somewhat) working is the following (which only works for `SIGINT`):

`PROMPT='%130(?.[$(kill -l $?)].$?)> '`

I have also tried using `precmd` but completely failed with that (it appears the return code is interfered with when zsh is executing the function but don't quote me on that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was indeed simple and just involved creating a different function (to which I passed the return code) rather than using `precmd`. Below is the final version of my zsh prompt, including the return code / signal behaviour:

```sh
code () {
  if (( $1 > 128 )); then
    echo "SIG$(kill -l $1)"
  else
    echo $1
  fi
}
setopt promptsubst
PROMPT='%F{green}%n%f@%m %F{cyan}%~%f> '
RPROMPT='%(?..%F{red}[$(code $?)]%f'
```